# npx create-react-app NOT working. Getting "outdated version of create-react-app" error

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

Please help. I've tried all what people have done already. I ran the commands below step by step as follows...

```html
node -v 
v17.3.0
npm -v
8.3.1
npx -v
8.3.1
yarn -v
1.22.17
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
yarn remove global create-react-app
npm cache clean -f
npm i -g npm@latest
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app@5.0.0
```

Been dealing with this bug for quite some time. Nobody has been able to solve it thus far.

Again, I cannot do npx create-react-app. It creates package.json file but not the template. I get the "need to uninstall global create-react-app" error. Windows 10 machine. Using bash inside VsCode.

I feel that up a directory or two, there is some hidden create-react-app file. But I've been the admin and ran these commands from the root directory C:/users/admin.

Does not work using yarn either.

It worked once I uninstalled nodejs and re-installed it again but then it starts error again later.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this -
install the latest react app modules locally in the working directory by using:

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

and then:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Runnning create-react-app with potential errors
npx create-react-app myapp
You are running create-react-app 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
The current solution is simple — run create-react-app and target the latest version.

Run creact-react-app using the latest version
npx create-react-app@latest myapp
Different versions of npm may help as well, and you can upgrade using the following command. Please note that this may affect other projects on your system.

Upgrading npm
npm install -g npm@latest   ( just wanted to post this for anybody who is having issues with npx create-react-app myapp.) I found this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting all files in npm folder, which are located in the `C/Users/"YourUser"/Appdata/Roaming/npm`, and the `npm-cache` folder, which is located in `C/Users/"YourUser"/Appdata/Roaming`.

Then try to run the `npx create-react-app react-app` command in the `C:/` folder. Do not create the project in the users folder.

**Note:** if you delete the files in the npm folder it will also remove all of the global packages installed on your pc.